# Parallelizing bulk of functions on multiple cpu environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I want to create a function that, given a list of functions and relative arguments, starts as much processes as possible in order to parallelize those tasks. The number of running processes can't be more than the number of cores of my CPU. When a process finishes, it should be replaced with another one, until the end.

I tried to implement such a thing using python Pools. Here's my function:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

CPUS = cpu_count()

def parallelize(functions, args):
    results = []
    if CPUS > 1:
        for i in xrange(0, len(functions), CPUS):
            pool = Pool()
            for j in xrange(CPUS):
                if i + j >= len(functions):
                    break
                results.append(pool.apply_async(functions[i + j], args = args[i + j]))
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
        map(lambda x: x.get(), results)
    else:
        for i in xrange(len(functions)):
            results.append(functions[i](*args[i]))
    return results
```

This implementation subdivides the list of functions in bulks. Each bulk dimension is equal to the number of the actual CPUs. The problem is that it actually waits until each bulk of functions finishes, and then starts again another bulk of processes.
I don't want this behavior because if there was a very slow function in a bulk, the other cpus will wait for it to finish before starting new processes.

What is the correct approach?

Comment: @dano `methods` is a list of functions. So `methods[i + j]` is a function. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I was thinking it was a slice for some reason. Ignore me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're over-complicating this. `multiprocessing.Pool` will always run with exactly the number of processes you tell it to, no matter how many work items you give to it. So if you create `Pool(CPUS)`, the `Pool` will never, ever, run more than `CPUS` tasks concurrently, even if you feed it `CPUS * 100` tasks. So it satisfies your requirement to never run more tasks than you have CPUs without you doing any special work. So, you can just iterate over your entire list of methods and args, and call `apply_async` on them without worrying about batching the calls at all. The `Pool` will execute all the tasks, but never more than `CPUS` tasks at a time:

```
def parallelize(methods, args):
    results = []
    if CPUS > 1:
        pool = Pool(CPUS)
        for method, arg in zip(methods, args):
            results.append(pool.apply_async(method, args=arg))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        out = map(lambda x: x.get(), results)
    else:
        for i in xrange(len(methods)):
            results.append(methods[i](*args[i]))
    return results
```

Comment: Oh, simpler than I expected. Thank you!